# Sharepoint 2010 how to add a wsp webpart

Tags: sharepoint, import, web-parts

We have got a Sharepoint project at school, we need to include some webparts like weather on a site; the point is that for importing webparts SP asks me for .dwp or .webpart files while I can only find .wsp . Where should I look for .webpart files ? Or how to import .wsp ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always use the sharepoint management shell.  Move your .wsp file to an easy location.  Open your management shell as an administrator and use this command:

```
add-spsolution c:\yourwsp.wsp
```

Open sharepoint central administration and manage farm solutions.  Deploy your webpart (System Settings - > Manage Farm Solutions) and then activate your webparts feature (Go to your desired web application Site Actions - > Site Settings - > Site Collection Features).

Edit:
When you are re-deploying a .wsp, make sure you go to your farm solutions and retract / remove your .wsp first.

Comment: Ok sorry I activated it in features but now how do I add it ?

Comment: I aplologize for the extreme delay.  You should be able to edit a page, go to the insert tab, select web part, navigate to the custom folder, and select it.

Answer (score 4):

open the PowerShell console (with admin credential) and

add:

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename "C:\yourwsp.wsp"

stsadm -o deploysolution -name yourwsp.wsp -url http://yourSPsite  -allowgacdeployment –immediate

stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

in the first line, you´re adding the wsp.
in the second line, you´re deploying the wsp.
and the last line, Powershell are executing the job.